# Database url with % in password not working with sqlalchemy

Tags: django, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm reading DATABASE_URL from env variable in uwsgi file. My django ORM connection is working with % in password but when I try to connect with sqlalchemy it is not working.

```
from sqlalchemy import orm, create_engine, MetaData
from app.settings import DATABASES
from urllib import quote_plus

con = "mysql+pymysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}".format(
        DATABASES['default']['USER'],
        DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'], 
        DATABASES['default']['HOST'],
        DATABASES['default']['PORT'],
        DATABASES['default']['NAME']
    )

engine = create_engine(
    con,
    echo=False,
    pool_recycle=1800,
    max_overflow = 250,
    pool_size=200
)
```

I even tried `quote_plus` but it did not worked.

This does not works 
`mysql+pymysql://api:@>J.6D%qhZ@localhost:3306/table_tmp`

This works
`mysql+pymysql://api:@>J.6DqhZ@localhost:3306/table_tmp`

When I use same password with **%** via ipython it works but via env variable in uwsgi.ini file it doesn't

Comment: I think problem here is because `%` should be escaped try replacing it with `%25`.

Comment: Tried that, it did not help.